# Can bad Karma gained by misunderstanding?

Tags: karma

Suppose someone pretending to be me said something or lied/spread lies, something bad about me & maybe about someone I know too,  to themselves(like Man-in-the-middle- attack)  who are dharmic innocent pure-hearted, void of any negative karma, who'd never wish or do bad to anyone, If they believe it, get hurt/take offence by misunderstanding thinking of me as those lies, would I get negative karma even when I did anything wrong to anyone, instead of true perprators? I think I'm dying, t why asking this question.